# Advanced JQ techniques

Tags: json, performance, jq

I'm looking for some help to increase my jq-foo, and could use a little guidance. I have some etl jobs that I script using JQ and I want to see if there is a way to make the runs more efficient in terms of CPU utilization and or speed.

Heres a sample payload:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1636601959,
  "uniqueId": "Foo",
  "value": 10
},
{
  "timestamp": 1636601859,
  "uniqueId": "Bar",
  "value": 13
}
```

and I want to do something like (pseudo-code):

```
if [ (epoch 15 minutes ago) -le timestamp ]; then 
   name=uniqueId; value_total=value(total); uniqueId_count=(uniqueId(count_total))
fi
```

Right now I do something like (pseudo-code):

```
for jq[timestamps] in $(json); do
  if [ (epoch 15 minutes ago)  -le timestamp ]; then 
    name=uniqueId; value_total=(value_total + value); uniqueId_count=(uniqueId_count + 1). 
  fi
done
```

Is there a way to simplify this without using a for loop to iterate over each object by calling `jq 'select() ...'` over and over?

Comment: Should the `.uniqueId_count` field in the output be totalling over the whole input or increasing from item to item?

Comment: That count would be the total number of times that uniqueId appears in the json document. So I basically need to get the total amount of groupby(uniqueids) that fall within the last 15 minutes. The value's would also be summed up in a similar manner. So if 'foo' appears at different timestamps but all within 15 minutes ago, I need the total value(10 + n + n + etc)

Comment: But in your pseudo-code, checking `timestamp -le (epoch 15 minutes ago)` would find those items **older than** 15 minutes, not "within the last 15 minutes"

Comment: Ah very true, i explained that incorrectly... it should be within 15 minutes... the actual code looks like this  `if [ "${minutes_ago}" -le "${time}" ]; then` where `minutes_ago` is the epoch 15 minutes ago and `time` is the json timestamp

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect all of the changes (I hope).

Comment: Really amazing!! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you either get rid of the commas between the objects or enclose the whole input with array brackets (in order to get proper JSON), then you can do (use the `-s` option for `{}{}{}` style, or drop it for `[{],{},{}]` style):

```sh
jq -s --argjson delta $((15*60)) --argjson addvalue 10 '

 (now - $delta) as $pivot
 | map(select(.timestamp >= $pivot))
 | group_by(.uniqueId)
 | map({
    name: first.uniqueId,
    value_total: map(.value) | (add + $addvalue),
    uniqueId_count: length
  })

'
```

Comment: This is awesome, thanks for this! Im going to give it a shot and see if I have any luck... would be great to not have to `for` loop over each object

Comment: Also I edited my OP, the value=10 should actually have been value_total=value(total)